# ¿como puedo hacer que un insert se ejecute despues del otro?

Tags: java, java-swing

ayuda lo que quiero hacer es que cuando le de a un botón  se ejecuten 3 insert uno de pues del otro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por por ejemplo tengo otras dos tablas donde esta el idregistro que necesito llenar y otra de software que también necesito llenar y quiero obtener los id de cada tabla y guardarla en esta que se ve aquí, aclaro todo por medio del netbeans. hasta ahora e intentado hacer esto:

```
public int GuardarRegistroCarn(int IDeq,String nombre_responsable,Date fecha,int idSemestre, String observasion, String nombre,String version ){
    int resultado = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Desea Guardar los datos actuales?");
     if(resultado == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
     Connection con = null;
     
            String sql;
            sql = "INSERT INTO registrocarnet (idEquipo,nombre_responsable,fecha,idSemestre,observaciones) Values(?,?,?,?,?)";
     
     
            System.out.println("los valores han sido agregados a la Base de Datos: ");
            
            try{
               con = metodospool.dataSource.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement psql = con.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                psql.setInt(1, IDeq);
                psql.setString(2, nombre_responsable);
                psql.setDate(3,  fecha);
                psql.setInt(4, idSemestre);
                psql.setString(5, observasion);
                
                
                resultado = psql.executeUpdate();
                ResultSet rs = psql.getGeneratedKeys();
                  while (rs.next()) {
                    int claveGeneradarc = rs.getInt(1);
                    System.out.println("Clave generada = " + claveGeneradarc);
                      }
                  psql.close();
    
                 String ssql;
            ssql = "INSERT INTO software (nombre,version) Values(?,?);";
            System.out.println("los valores han sido agregados a la Base de Datos: ");
            PreparedStatement ppsql = con.prepareStatement(ssql);
               
                ppsql.setString(1, nombre);
                ppsql.setString(2, version);
                resultado = ppsql.executeUpdate();
                ResultSet rss = ppsql.getGeneratedKeys();
                  while (rs.next()) {
                    int claveGeneradasw = rss.getInt(1);
                    System.out.println("Clave generada = " + claveGeneradasw);
                      }
                  ppsql.close();
                
                 String sssql;
                 sssql = "INSERT INTO repswequip (idRegistroCarnetl,idSoftware) Values(?,?);";
                 System.out.println("los valores han sido agregados a la Base de Datos: ");
            PreparedStatement pppsql = con.prepareStatement(sssql);
            pppsql.setInt(1, rs.getInt(1));
            pppsql.setInt(2, rss.getInt(1));
            resultado = pppsql.executeUpdate();
            pppsql.close();
            }catch(SQLException e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al intentar almacenar los datos: "
                        + e,"Error en la Operacion", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
            }finally{
                try{
                    if(con != null)
                        con.close();
                }catch(SQLException e){
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al intentar Cerrar la Conexion: "
                        + e,"Error en la Operacion", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
                }
            }
     }
            return resultado;
}
```

este es el método que utilizo para guardar la información y en la que quiero guardar todo

Comment: Y que error te produce lo que tienes hasta ahora?

Comment: me sale el error java.sql.sqlException: Generated keys not requested. you need to specify statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS to Statement.executeUpdate(),statement.executeLargeUpdate() or Connection.prepareStatement()

Comment: si guarda los 2 lo que no guarda es el ultimo insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu error radica en tu segundo insert, ya que usas `getGeneratedKeys`, pero en tu `prepareStatement` (cosa que si haces en el primero).

Primer statement

```
PreparedStatement psql = con.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

Segundo statement

PreparedStatement ppsql = con.prepareStatement(ssql);

Lo único que tienes que hacer es agregar esa opción al segundo statement

```
PreparedStatement ppsql = con.prepareStatement(ssql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
ppsql.setString(1, nombre);
ppsql.setString(2, version);
resultado = ppsql.executeUpdate();
ResultSet rss = ppsql.getGeneratedKeys();
```

Nota, que esto solo es necesario cuando vas a usar `getGeneratedKeys();` En tu tercer `Statement` no lo usas, por lo que no sería necesario agregar esa opción al hacer `prepareStatement`

Comment: gracias me sirvio

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que pides es ejecutar tres inserts uno tras otro obteniendo una información del insert anterior y luego utilizarlo para el siguiente, te sugiero que hagas una condición if (....) y dentro ejecutas la segunda consulta. de esa manera controlas si se ha ejecutado bien las consultas anteriores antes de seguir con el proceso.

Comment: disculpa como se haría, es que soy novato en esto y no se como hacer los if